# Problem in VB.Net Socket Server

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets

I have a asynchronous vb.net socket server and my client is in Flash AS3. Only one time server code is accepting the data from the client. Very first request is accepted by the server and it sends the response to the client. After the first request server stops sending data. Below is my server code in vb.net

```
Public Class WWGServer
    Protected portNumber As Integer
    Protected maxSockets As Integer
    Protected sockCount As Integer = 0
    Private convID As Integer = 0
    Private lostTimer As Threading.Timer
    Private Const numThreads As Integer = 1
    Private Const timerTimeout As Integer = 300000
    Private Const timeoutMinutes As Integer = 3
    Private ShuttingDown As Boolean = False
    Protected title As String
    Protected connectedHT As New Hashtable()
    Protected connectedSocks As ArrayList

    'Thread signal.
    Private allDone As New ManualResetEvent(False)
    Private serverThread As Thread() = New Thread(numThreads - 1) {}
    Private threadEnd As AutoResetEvent() = New AutoResetEvent(numThreads - 1) {}

    'UI
    Private _lsvLog As WWG.ListView.GWWList
    Delegate Sub WriteToLogDelegate(ByVal entry As String)

    Public Sub New(ByVal port As Integer, ByVal title As String, ByVal attr As String, ByVal lsvLog As WWG.ListView.GWWList)
        Me.portNumber = port
        Me.title = title
        Me.maxSockets = 10000
        _lsvLog = lsvLog
        connectedSocks = New ArrayList(Me.maxSockets)
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteToLogMethod(ByVal entry As String)
        'log.Text.Insert(log.Text.Length - 2, Chr(13) & entry)
        If _lsvLog.Count > 1000 Then
            Dim iIndex As Integer

            For iIndex = 0 To _lsvLog.Items.Count - 1
                _lsvLog.Items.Remove(iIndex)
            Next
        End If

        Dim _lsvLogItem As WWG.ListView.GWWItem = _lsvLog.Items.Add(Now())
        _lsvLogItem.SubItems(1).Text = entry
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteToLog(ByVal entry As String)
        Dim logDelegate As New WriteToLogDelegate(AddressOf WriteToLogMethod)
        If _lsvLog.InvokeRequired() Then
            _lsvLog.Invoke(logDelegate, entry)
        Else
            logDelegate(entry)
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' 
    ''' Description: Start the threads to listen to the port and process
    ''' messages.
    ''' 
    Public Sub Start()
        ' Clear the thread end events
        For lcv As Integer = 0 To numThreads - 1
            threadEnd(lcv) = New AutoResetEvent(False)
        Next

        Dim threadStart1 As New ThreadStart(AddressOf StartListening)
        serverThread(0) = New Thread(threadStart1)
        serverThread(0).IsBackground = True
        serverThread(0).Start()

        ' Create the delegate that invokes methods for the timer.
        'Dim timerDelegate As New TimerCallback(AddressOf Me.CheckSockets)
        ' Create a timer that waits one minute, then invokes every 5 minutes.
        'lostTimer = New Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, Nothing, WWGServer.timerTimeout, WWGServer.timerTimeout)
        WriteToLogMethod("Started..")
    End Sub

    ''' 
    ''' Description: Check for dormant sockets and close them.
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="eventState">Required parameter for a timer call back
    ''' method.</param>
    Private Sub CheckSockets(ByVal eventState As Object)

        lostTimer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)

        Try
            For Each state As StateObject In connectedSocks
                If state.workSocket Is Nothing Then
                    ' Remove invalid state object
                    Monitor.Enter(connectedSocks)
                    If connectedSocks.Contains(state) Then
                        connectedSocks.Remove(state)
                        Interlocked.Decrement(sockCount)
                    End If
                    Monitor.[Exit](connectedSocks)
                Else
                    If DateTime.Now.AddTicks(-state.TimeStamp.Ticks).Minute > timeoutMinutes Then
                        RemoveSocket(state)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
            lostTimer.Change(WWGServer.timerTimeout, WWGServer.timerTimeout)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
    ''' 
    ''' Decription: Stop the threads for the port listener.
    ''' 
    Public Sub [Stop]()
        Dim lcv As Integer
        lostTimer.Dispose()
        lostTimer = Nothing

        For lcv = 0 To numThreads - 1
            If Not serverThread(lcv).IsAlive Then
                threadEnd(lcv).[Set]()
                ' Set event if thread is already dead
            End If
        Next
        ShuttingDown = True
        ' Create a connection to the port to unblock the listener thread
        Dim sock As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        Dim endPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Me.portNumber)
        sock.Connect(endPoint)
        sock.Close()
        sock = Nothing

        ' Check thread end events and wait for up to 5 seconds.
        For lcv = 0 To numThreads - 1
            threadEnd(lcv).WaitOne(5000, False)
        Next
    End Sub

    ''' 
    ''' Decription: Open a listener socket and wait for a connection.
    ''' 
    Private Sub StartListening()
        ' Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        Dim localEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Me.portNumber)
        ' Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Dim listener As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

        WriteToLog("Started Lisenting")

        ' Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.

        Try
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint)
            listener.Listen(1000)

            While Not ShuttingDown
                ' Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset()
                ' Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.

                listener.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.AcceptCallback), listener)

                ' Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne()
            End While
        Catch e As Exception
            threadEnd(0).[Set]()
        End Try
    End Sub

    ''' 
    ''' Decription: Call back method to accept new connections.
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="ar">Status of an asynchronous operation.</param>
    Private Sub AcceptCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        WriteToLog(Now())
        ' Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.[Set]()
        ' Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Dim listener As Socket = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
        Dim handler As Socket = listener.EndAccept(ar)

        ' Create the state object.
        Dim state As New StateObject()
        state.workSocket = handler
        state.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now

        Try

            Interlocked.Increment(sockCount)
            Monitor.Enter(connectedSocks)
            connectedSocks.Add(state)
            Monitor.[Exit](connectedSocks)
            Dim socketAddr As System.Net.SocketAddress
            socketAddr = handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize()

            Dim strIP As String = handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(4).ToString() & "." & handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(5).ToString() & "." & handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(6).ToString() & "." & handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(7).ToString()

            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.ReadCallback), state)

            If sockCount > Me.maxSockets Then

                'RemoveSocket(state)
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
                handler.Close()
                handler = Nothing
                state = Nothing
            End If
        Catch es As SocketException
            'RemoveSocket(state)
        Catch e As Exception            
            'RemoveSocket(state)
        End Try
    End Sub

    ''' 
    ''' Decription: Call back method to handle incoming data.
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="ar">Status of an asynchronous operation.</param>
    Protected Sub ReadCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)

        Dim content As [String] = [String].Empty
        ' Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        ' from the async state object.
        Dim state As StateObject = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, StateObject)
        Dim handler As Socket = state.workSocket

        Dim strIP As String = handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(4).ToString() & "." & handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(5).ToString() & "." & handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(6).ToString() & "." & handler.RemoteEndPoint.Serialize(7).ToString()

        Try
            ' Read data from the client socket.
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = handler.EndReceive(ar)

            If bytesRead > 0 Then
                ' There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                'Monitor.Enter(state)
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead))
                'Monitor.[Exit](state)
                ' Check for end-of-file tag.
                ' If it is not there, read more data.
                content = state.sb.ToString()
                'if (content.IndexOf("") > -1)
                If (content.Length > 0) AndAlso ((content(0) <> "<"c) OrElse ((content(0) = "<"c) AndAlso (content.IndexOf("") > -1))) Then
                    'WriteToLog(Dns.GetHostEntry(strIP).HostName & ":" & content)
                    Send(handler, GameData.GetXML(content))
                    state.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now
                Else
                    ' Not all data received. Get more.
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.ReadCallback), state)
                End If
            Else
                ' Disconnected
                'RemoveSocket(state)
            End If
        Catch es As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
            RemoveSocket(state)
            If es.ErrorCode <> 64 Then
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ReadCallback Socket Exception: {0}, {1}.", es.ErrorCode, es.ToString()))
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            RemoveSocket(state)
            If e.[GetType]().FullName <> "System.ObjectDisposedException" Then
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("ReadCallback Exception: {0}.", e.ToString()))
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Send(ByVal sock As Socket, ByVal data As String)
        ' Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        Dim byteData As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

        ' Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        If byteData.Length > 0 Then
            sock.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf Me.SendCallback), sock)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub SendCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        ' Retrieve the socket from the async state object.
        Dim handler As Socket = DirectCast(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
        Try
            ' Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            Dim bytesSent As Integer = handler.EndSend(ar)
        Catch e As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function FindID(ByVal id As String) As Socket
        Dim sock As Socket = Nothing
        Monitor.Enter(connectedHT)
        If connectedHT.ContainsKey(id) Then
            sock = DirectCast(connectedHT(id), Socket)
        End If
        Monitor.[Exit](connectedHT)
        Return sock
    End Function

    Protected Overridable Function StuffList(ByVal state As StateObject, ByVal command As String, ByRef content As String) As Boolean
        Dim sock As Socket = state.workSocket
        Dim hostID As String = ""
        ' ReadXML(command, Server.msgConnect, this.connectAttr);
        If hostID IsNot Nothing Then
            state.id = hostID
            'if (hostID == Server.webServer)
            '        {
            '          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Host control socket connected {0}!",this.title));
            '             return true;
            '        }


            ' Add to connected list
            Monitor.Enter(connectedHT)
            If connectedHT.ContainsKey(hostID) Then
                Dim val As Object = connectedHT(hostID)
                connectedHT(hostID) = sock
                connectedHT.Add(sock, val)
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Socket found in Hashtable!", Me.title))
            Else
                connectedHT.Add(hostID, sock)
                connectedHT.Add(sock, hostID)
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Socket not found, adding a new socket to hashtable!", Me.title))
            End If
            Monitor.[Exit](connectedHT)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Socket was moved to connected {0} list!", Me.title))
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    ''' 
    ''' Description: Remove the socket contained in the given state object
    ''' from the connected array list and hash table, then close the socket.
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="state">The StateObject containing the specific socket
    ''' to remove from the connected array list and hash table.</param>
    Protected Overridable Sub RemoveSocket(ByVal state As StateObject)
        Dim sock As Socket = state.workSocket
        Monitor.Enter(connectedSocks)
        If connectedSocks.Contains(state) Then
            connectedSocks.Remove(state)
            Interlocked.Decrement(sockCount)
        End If
        Monitor.[Exit](connectedSocks)
        Monitor.Enter(connectedHT)

        If (sock IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (connectedHT.ContainsKey(sock)) Then
            Dim sockTemp As Object = connectedHT(sock)
            If connectedHT.ContainsKey(sockTemp) Then
                If connectedHT.ContainsKey(connectedHT(sockTemp)) Then
                    connectedHT.Remove(sock)
                    If sock.Equals(connectedHT(sockTemp)) Then
                        connectedHT.Remove(sockTemp)
                    Else
                        Dim val As Object, key As Object = sockTemp
                        While True
                            val = connectedHT(key)
                            If sock.Equals(val) Then
                                connectedHT(key) = sockTemp
                                Exit While
                            ElseIf connectedHT.ContainsKey(val) Then
                                key = val
                            Else
                                ' The chain is broken
                                Exit While
                            End If
                        End While
                    End If
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Socket is not in the {0} connected hash table!", Me.title))
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Monitor.[Exit](connectedHT)

        If sock IsNot Nothing Then
            'if (sock.Connected)
            '    sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sock.Close()
            sock = Nothing
            state.workSocket = Nothing

            state = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

My AS3 Client code is below 

function utilLoadCompleted(event:Event)
        {

            _connectServer = new GameServer(Main.util.server,Main.util.port);

            _connectServer.addEventListener("onConnectServer",serverRequest);
            _connectServer.addEventListener("OnServerResponse",serverResponse);


        }

        function getDataFromServer(strType:String)
        {
            reqType = strType;
            if (reqType == "SCORE")
            {
                _connectServer.sendRequest("GETSCORE," + Main.util.cardNo);
            }
            else if (reqType == "PAYTABLE")
            {
                _connectServer.sendRequest("PAYTABLE,game6," + String(Main.levelSel));
            }
            else if (reqType == "REVEAL")
            {
                _connectServer.sendRequest("KENO," + Main.util.cardNo + ",game6," + String(pickTiles.length) + "," + txtPlayLevel.text + "," + txtPlayPoints.text);
            }
        }

        function serverRequest(event:Event)
        {
            getDataFromServer("SCORE");         
        }

        function serverResponse(evt:DataEvent)
        {
            //trace(evt.data);

            try
            {
                if (reqType == "SCORE")
                {
                    _xml = XML(evt.data);
                    var customer:XML = _xml.AccountDetails[0];
                    txtTotalWin.text = customer.TotalWin;
                    txtTotalPoints.text = customer.TotalEntries;

                }
                else if (reqType == "PAYTABLE")
                {
                    Main.paytableXml = XML(evt.data);
                }
                else if (reqType == "REVEAL")
                {
                    xml = XML(evt.data);
                    Main.gameXml = xml;
                    trace(xml);
                    xmlloadComplete(xml);
                }

                /*_connectServer.Disconnect();
                _connectServer = null;*/

            }
            catch (errObject:Error)
            {
                fscommand("SERVERERROR","true");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tut, tut. Haven't spotted what's wrong that led to this question, but you've got code manipulating a collection inside of a `For Each` iterating it (`connectedSocks.Remove(state)`). That's generally not supported.